# Property address database design in DynamoDB NoSQL

Tags: database, nosql

We have several terabytes of address data and are investigating the possibility of storing this in a DynamoDB NoSQL database. I've done quite a bit of reading on DynamoDB and NoSQL in general, but am coming from many years of MS SQL and am struggling with some of the NoSQL concepts.

My biggest question at this point is how to setup the table structure so that I can accommodate the various different ways the data could be queried. For example, in regular SQL I would expect some queries like:

WHERE Address LIKE '%maple st%' AND ZipCode = 12345

WHERE Address LIKE '%poplar ln%' AND City = 'Los Angeles' AND State = 'CA'

WHERE OwnerName LIKE '%smith%' AND CountyFIPS = '00239'

Those are just examples. The actual queries could be any combination of those various fields.

It's not clear to me what my index should look like or how the table (or tables) should be structured. Can anyone get me started on understanding how that could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is relatively old, but I will try to give you an answer (maybe it will be helpful for someone having similar issues in the future).

DynamoDB is not really meant to be used in the way you describe. Its strengths are in fast (smoking fast in fact) look-ups of key/value pairs. To take your example of IP address if you wanted to really quickly look-up information associated with an IP address you could easily make the HashKey a string with the IP address and use this to do a look-up.

Things start to get complicated when you want to do queries (or scans) in dynamoDb, you can read about them here: [Query and Scan in DynamDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)

The gist being that scans/queries are really expensive when not performed on either the HaskKey or HaskKey+RangeKey combo (range keys are basically composite keys).

In other words I am not sure if DynamoDb is the right way to go. For smoking fast search functionality I would consider using something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). If you configure your indexes wisely you will be amazed how fast it works.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Seems Amazon has now added support for secondary indices:
[See here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/04/local-secondary-indexes-for-amazon-dynamodb.html)

Answer (score 0):

> DynamoDB was built to be utilized in the way the question author describes refer to this [LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html) where AWS documentation describes creating a secondary index like this

```
[country]#[region]#[state]#[county]#[city]#[neighborhood]
```

The partition key could be something like this as well based on what you want to look up.

In DynamoDB, you create the joins before you create the table. This means that you have to think about all the ways you intend to search for you data, create the indexes, and query your data using them.

AWS created [AWS noSQL WorkBench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) to help teams do this. There are a few UI bugs in that application at the time of this writing; refer to [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768971/dynamodb-nosql-workbench-test-table-not-visible/67578311#67578311) for more information on the bugs.

To review some of the queries you mentioned, I'll share a few possibilities in which you can create an index to create that query.

> **Note:** noSQL means denormalized data in some cases, but not necessarily.

There are limits as to how keys should be shaped so that dynamoDB can partition actual servers to scale; refer to [partition keys](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) for more info.

The magic of dynamoDB is a well thought out model that can also handle new queries after the table is created and being used in production. There are a great deal of posts and video's online that explain how to do this.

Here is one with Rick Houlihan [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn12QSNa4RE&t=1293s). Rick Houlihan is the principle designer of DynamoDB, so go there for gospel.

To make the queries you're attempting, one would create multiple keys, mainly an initial partition key and secondary key. Rick recommends keeping them generic like PK, and SK.

Then try to shape the PK with a great deal of uniqueness e.g. A partition key of a zip code PK: "12345" could contain a massive amount of data that may be more than the 10GB quota for any partition key limit.

> Example 1: WHERE Address LIKE '%maple st%' AND ZipCode = 12345

For example 1, we could shape a partition key of PK: "12345:maple"
Then just calling the PK of "12345:maple" would retrieve all the data with that zip code as well as street of maple. There will be many different PK's and that is what dynamoDB does well: scales horizontally.

> Example 2: WHERE Address LIKE '%poplar ln%' AND City = 'Los Angeles' AND State = 'CA'

In example 2, we could then use the secondary index to add another way to be more specific such as PK: "12345:poplar" SK: "losangeles:ca:other:info:that:helps"

> Example 3: WHERE OwnerName LIKE '%smith%' AND CountyFIPS = '00239'

For example 3, we don't have a street name. We would need to know the street name to query the data, but we may not have it in a search. This is where one would need to fully understand their base query patterns and shape the PK to be easily known at the time of the query while still being quite unique so that we do not go over the partition limits. Having a street name would probably not be the most optimal, it all depends on what queries are required.

In this last example, it may be more appropriate to add some global secondary indices, which just means making new primary key and secondary keys that map to data attribute (column) like CountyFIPS.