# DynamoDB NoSQL Workbench test table not visible

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm new on DynamoDB and using NoSQL Workbench to learn. There is a new "Example" table in "Data modeler" section. I made a new LOCAL connection under "Operation builder" section to work on/test the "Example" table. Connection was created successfully and there was no error. But I can't see any table under Connection part. It says "No table found". I can't understand the problem. I think, I should see the "Example" table that is visible under "Data modeler" section. How can I see the table in Connection section?

Comment: The tool was working fine when I was using it with localstack 0.12.12 but then I had to upgrade to fix an issue with the default response to a put() and not it doesn't show anything. aws dynamo describe-table works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As of Version 3.0 May 17th 2021 - macOS Big Sur

NoSQL Workbench is buggy.

I have worked through several different bugs in the system.

- You may have to completely close the application and restart it to get some items to show including the table or a new global secondary index
- There are some expanding selection menus that work on the second or third try.
- Toggle between menu items on the left.
- If you have selected a query and nothing is showing up, select another type like getitem and then re-select query to update the UI.

It seams there are a few bugs due to the screen not refreshing the UI at the appropriate times.

I've worked through the above items and now I can use the application, just have to work through the above recommendations from time to time.

This is a beta level application, but still a bit useful when entering into DynamoDB data modeling.

Even Rick Houlihan had some issues with it during his performance:
[Using the NoSQL Workbench to build a purchase order application on DynamoDB with Rick Houlihan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn12QSNa4RE&t=1293s)

Comment: Still true in Aug. 2023. It's like they don't care about the product. It's not even usable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the table and add items to it. You can add items to the table in the visualizer section, and then commit the items to DynamoDB.

Comment: Have you tried this recently? I’m only able to get it working with the models.  When I try to commit data the rows do not get pushed but the model seems to do fine

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL WorkBench to view, you can put the directory name as the same as the image to be uploaded

An example using localstack:

**Create the following directory on your computer:**

```
|
|docker
||
| localstack
| |
|  |docker-compose.yml
|
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: localstack
    image: localstack/localstack
    hostname: localstack
...
```

**Navigate to directory with CMD:**

```
cd docker/localstack
```

**Run:**

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**Create new connection in NoSQL Workbench \ Operation Builder:**

```
Connection name: localstack
Hostname: localstack
Port: 4566
```

[image: Image Example NoSQL Workbench \ Operation Builder]

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the original question, but if you use NoSQL workbench to view a table that exists in a DynamoDB Docker contaier, you need to run the container with the `-sharedDB` parameter.

For example:

```golang
resource, _ := pool.RunWithOptions(&dockertest.RunOptions{
        Cmd:          []string{"-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-sharedDb"}, // to be able to inspect in NoSQL workbench
        Repository:   "amazon/dynamodb-local",
        Tag:          "latest",
        // ...
    }, func(hostConfig *docker.HostConfig) {
        hostConfig.AutoRemove = true
    })
```

Demo: https://github.com/miparnisari/DynamoDBTests/blob/302b364da04837779644c13e8a0e8cec54d931bf/main.go#L85

If you put a breakpoint after the table has been created but you remove that parameter, you won't be able to see the table in NoSQL workbench.