# DynamoDB NoSQL Workbench local table not visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamo-local

I am connecting to a local DynamoDB and was able to create 2 tables and added data to each. However I am unable to see the 2nd table under, "Operation builder".

I have tired to commit the table again and get an error saying the table exists. See below

[image]

From "Operation builder" I've clicked on the "Table" refresh icon and the 2nd table "grades" will not show up.

[image]

I have tried closing down and re-running NoSQL Workbench, but I still getting have the same problem. Committing the missing table again gives me the error it already exist.

Answer (score 1):

As it's stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768971/dynamodb-nosql-workbench-test-table-not-visible) thread, NoSQL Workbench is definitely buggy. I was having similar problems with my recently created GSIs and I am pretty sure I had already tried restarting the APP. Nevertheless, I probably did that by closing and opening the APP with the "X" button above. Still not seeing my updated GSIs. I have just done the same using the "Quit" option from the "Application" menu, and now it worked. Not sure if that was the reason or it was just a matter of time syncing...But you can always try.

[image: Quit from Menu]