# DynamoDB table created by Terraform in LocalStack not visible in NoSQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws, localstack

**Summary**: Code and configuration known to show up in NoSQL Workbench when using DynamoDB Local mysteriously don't work with LocalStack: though the connection works, the tables no longer show in NoSQL Workbench (but continue to show up when using the `aws-cli`).

---

I created a table in [DynamoDB Local running in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) that worked in [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html). I wrote code to seed that database, and it all worked and showed up in NoSQL Workbench.

I switched to [LocalStack](https://localstack.cloud/) (so I can interact with other AWS services locally). I was able to create a table with Terraform and can seed it with my code (using the configuration given [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/custom-service-endpoints#localstack)). Using the `aws-cli`, I can see the table, etc.

But inside NoSQL Workbench, I couldn't see the table I created and seeded when connecting as shown below. There weren't connection errors; the table just isn't there. It doesn't seem related to the bugginess issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135719/dynamodb-nosql-workbench-local-table-not-visible), as restarting the application did not help. I didn't change any AWS account settings like region, keys, etc.

[image: NoSQL Workbench screenshot showing connection settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary**: To use NoSQL Workbench with LocalStack, set the region to `localhost` in your code and Terraform config, and fix the resulting validation error (saying there isn't a `localhost` region) by setting `skip_region_validation` to true in the `aws` provider block in the Terraform config.

---

The problem is disclosed in the screenshot above:

[image: Help text in NoSQL Workbench]

NoSQL Workbench uses the `localhost` region.

When using DynamoDB Local, it appears the [region is ignored](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html#DynamoDBLocal.Differences), so this quirk is hidden (i.e. there *is* a mismatch between the region in the Terraform file and my code on the one hand and NoSQL Workbench on the other, but it doesn't matter with DyanmoDB Local).

But with LocalStack region is not ignored, so the problem popped up.

I wouldn't have written this up except for one more quirk that took a while to figure out. When I updated the Terraform configuration thus:

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "mock_access_key"
  // For compatibility with NoSQL workbench local connections
  region                      = "localhost"
```

I started getting this error when running `terraform apply`:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid AWS Region: localhost
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│
╵
```

I dug around a bit and found this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17882#issuecomment-788967744) in the AWS provider repo for Terraform, which explains that you should do this:

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "mock_access_key"
  // For compatibility with NoSQL workbench local connections
  region                      = "localhost"
  skip_region_validation      = true
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change your region to localhost, there is another solution. From the LocalStack [docs](https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/configuration/#dynamodb):

"DYNAMODB_SHARE_DB: When activated, DynamodDB will use a single database instead of separate databases for each credential and region."

e.g. add the variable to your docker-compose.yml

```
  ...

  localstack:
    container_name: my_localstack
    image: "localstack/localstack:0.13.0.8"
    environment:
      - DYNAMODB_SHARE_DB=1   

  ...
```